# Ranged for loop const reference doesn't seem to make a difference

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a range based for loop in C++11,

```
for(auto const &ticket : ticketStrip->tickets()) {
  ticket->ClearCalled();
}
```

Why am I able to call non const methods on the ticket within the loop, such as ClearCalled() when it is not marked as const?

```
void Ticket::ClearCalled() { ... }
```

ClearCalled does indeed modify the ticket internals, so it shouldn't be marked as const. I know I should be using

```
auto &ticket
```

but I just tried

```
auto const &ticket
```

and the compiler accepted it.

The type of ticket is

```
boost::shared_ptr<AbstractMainStageTicket>
```

and putting some new code in:

```
ticket->ClearCalled();
ticket.reset();
```

makes the compiler flag up the error that reset is not const.

Thanks for your help!

I'm using the GNU 4.6 toolchain for Android.

Comment: If you're calling it with `->` that implies `ticket` is an iterator. So you have a constant iterator and not an iterator to const. What's tickets() type?

Comment: Sorry, it's actually a smart pointer, and that answers my question, I can modify what the smart pointer is pointing at, but not the smart pointer itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From your syntax it seems that `ticket` is a (smart?) pointer.

```
ticket->ClearCalled();
```

Which means that the type of `ticket` is probably something like

```
const std::shared_ptr< Ticket >& ticket
```

What you would need is

```
const std::shared_ptr< const Ticket >& ticket;
//                     ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I got confused over the fact that I was dealing with smart pointers.